# how to make firefox or any other xulrunner based app float above all other windows in mac 10.6 and above?

Tags: macos, firefox, osx-snow-leopard

afloat is very useful to keep the window above all the windows in mac, but only cocoa based applications. Is there a way that one can achieve this feature for other applications programmatically. example firefox

I do not want to use afloat, but I would like to know how to code this feature in mac.

Thanks a lot!!